# communicate with another process (same source code) via wndProc in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm working on implementing communicate with another process via `HwndSource` in WPF.

I want My Program (Let's call it `A`) to communicate with My Program (also `A`) that is on another process on windows.
following images will help me to explain what I've been doing and what I want to implement.

[image: image1]

two windows are exactly same program (just different background-color), and they know exactly their Handle each other. If I notice two process have same title, then I call `sendMessage` which is defined in `user32.dll` with Message -Raw input message constant that can pump message globally- `0x0100`**WM_KEYDOWN**.

```cs
// if same program - but different process
IntPtr lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("Hi, Im Sender");
MessageBox.Show(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(lpData));
DisplayAnotherProcessHandle.Text = p.MainWindowHandle.ToString();

SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_RawInput_key, IntPtr.Zero, lpData);
```

I successfully pass `WM_RawInput_Key`, `IntPtr.Zero` to opponent program. but I have problem with lParam. I can't get lParam data. I tried to Marshal `c# string` with `Marshal.StringToBSTR` or `Marshal.StringToAuto` ... but in following method I just get `Empty.String`.

```cs
private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
  if (msg != WM_RawInput_key) return IntPtr.Zero;

  if (wParam == IntPtr.Zero)  // <-- opponent process hit this conditional syntax nicely.
  {
    var str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(lParam);  // but I'm failed pass lParam, or Marshalling lParam I don't know ...
    MessageBox.Show(str);
    DisplaySucceedOrNot.Text = str;
  }

  return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

I don't know which memory parameter `IntPtr lParam` indicates. I don't know even this technique is valid. I need your help. thank you for reading

following source code is my entire source code of example program.

```xml
<Window x:Class="wndProc_IPC_WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wndProc_IPC_WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WndProc-IPC-WPF" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="AddHandler" Width="Auto" Height="100" Content="Add Handler to This Handle" Click="AddHandler_Click"></Button>
        <Button Name="CreateNewProcess" Width="Auto" Height="100" Content="Create New Process Window" Click="CreateNewProcess_Click"></Button>
        <Button Width="Auto" Height="100" Content="SendMessage To Another Process" Name="SendMessageBtn" Click="SendMessage_Click"></Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="MyHandle : "></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="DisplayMyProcessHandle" Margin="50 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Another Handle : "></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="DisplayAnotherProcessHandle" Margin="50 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Succed?"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="DisplaySucceedOrNot" Margin="50 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    string AppName;
    public static UInt32 WM_RawInput_key = 0x0100;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AppName = this.Title;
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg != WM_RawInput_key) return IntPtr.Zero;

        if (wParam == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            var str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(lParam);
            MessageBox.Show(str);
            DisplaySucceedOrNot.Text = str;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private void CreateNewProcess_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(AppName).Length > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Already 2 Process Exist.");
            return;
        }
        var path = (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        p.Start();
    }

    private void SendMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName(AppName))
        {
            if (p.MainWindowHandle == Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle) continue; 

            {
                IntPtr lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("Hi, Im Sender");
                MessageBox.Show(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(lpData));
                DisplayAnotherProcessHandle.Text = p.MainWindowHandle.ToString();

                SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_RawInput_key, IntPtr.Zero, lpData);

            }
        }
    }

    private void AddHandler_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
        source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wparam` and `lparam` are just a pointers to your local process memory, which the other process cannot access. The `wparam` works well in your example as you just process the pointer value and not the data the it points to.

For a similar purpose I used [`WM_COPYDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata?redirectedfrom=MSDN) message where you provide a pointer to a [`COPYDATASTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-copydatastruct). There you can encapsulate also complex data structs, which can be handled read-only in your receiving process.

Microsoft provides a useful example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-data-copy

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mihaeru, actually I was on finding example source of `sendMessage/wndProc` with `WM_COPYDATA` in Wpf after posting my question. Like Raw-Input message `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_COPYDATA` also provide global message pump(right?, I don't know exact theory on old windows... -_-;;)

I failed many times. and I found that I should allocate `cbData` with Length of string. if I add Attribute `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LpWStr)]` which 2 byte per character, then I need allocate `string.length*2` to cbData.

I succeed to pass message to opponent process.

[image]

following source is answer source

```cs
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;
            public int cbData;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string lpData;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

        string AppName;
        public static UInt32 WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AppName = this.Title;
        }

        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if (msg != WM_COPYDATA) return IntPtr.Zero;

            if (wParam == IntPtr.Zero)
            {

                COPYDATASTRUCT cd = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
                cd = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
                MessageBox.Show(cd.lpData);
                DisplaySucceedOrNot.Text = cd.lpData;
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        private void CreateNewProcess_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Process.GetProcessesByName(AppName).Length > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Already 2 Process Exist.");
                return;
            }
            var path = (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
            p.Start();
        }

        private void SendMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName(AppName))
            {
                if (p.MainWindowHandle == Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle) continue;

                {
                    IntPtr lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("Hi, Im Sender");

                    COPYDATASTRUCT cd = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
                    cd.lpData = "Hi, Im Sender";
                    cd.dwData = p.MainWindowHandle;
                    cd.cbData = cd.lpData.Length+1;

                    MessageBox.Show(cd.lpData);
                    DisplayAnotherProcessHandle.Text = p.MainWindowHandle.ToString();
                    SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, ref cd);
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddHandler_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);

            source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
            DisplayMyProcessHandle.Text = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle.ToString();
        }
```